# Laurent series/isolated singularity

Tags: taylor-expansion, residue-calculus, laurent-series, singularity

I want to classify the singularities of
$$ f(z)=\frac{\sin(2z)}{(z-1)^3}$$

The Taylor series is:  $\sin(2z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} 2^{2k+1} z^{2k+1}$

So:

$ \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} 2^{2k+1} z^{2k+1}}{(z-1)^3}$.

How can I go on from there?

Comment: The undefined points, i.e. the possible singularities are $z=1$, so I think you should expand $\sin (2z)$ around $z = 1$, not $z = 0$. I *guess* it is a pole of order $3$.

Comment: Okay clearly I have guessed wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go nowhere from that. Insted, use the fact that\begin{align}\sin(2z)&=\sin\bigl(2(z-1)+2\bigr)\\&=\sin\bigl(2(z-1)\bigr)\cos(2)+\cos\bigl(2(z-1)\bigr)\sin(2)\end{align}and expand in power series centered at $1$ the functions $\sin\bigl(2(z-1)\bigr)$ and $\cos\bigl(2(z-1)\bigr)$.

Comment: I see:) Then I can see that I have a pole of order 3. The residue would be $\frac{-4}{3}$. Did I calculate that right?

Comment: The residue is $\frac{-4}{3} cos2$.    The power series of cos  has no $(z-1)^{-1}$, so the residue can be only determined by the series of sin(2(z-1))

Comment: No. The residue is $-2\sin(2)$.

Comment: The pole of order 3 is right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Yes I found -2 sin(2), Thank you:) Dou you maybe know how I can compute $\frac{cos^2 z}{sin^2  z}$

Comment: Thank you very much:) Do you maybe have an idea for my other problem: $\frac{cos^2 z}{sin^2  z}$  Maybe I can write: $ \frac{1-sin^2z}{sin^2 z } = \frac{1}{sin^2 } -1  $ How can I go on from there?